# RippleDrawable created programmatically looks different from its xml counterpart

Tags: android, button, material-design, rippledrawable

I have been trying to trace this issue for a while now. I think I did find an explanation some time ago. Unfortunately, its lost in code-comments somewhere.

I am trying to create a `Material Borderless-Button` in Java. To start with, here's what the button looks like in the framework:

Button bg (*button_borderless_material.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@id/mask"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape" />
</ripple>
```

The `drawable` being used as mask (*btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Used as the canonical button shape. -->
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
       android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
       android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
           android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                 android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                 android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Java equivalent of the `inset-drawable` (*btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml*):

```
Drawable createButtonShape(Context context, int color) {
    Resource res = context.getResources();
    int radius = res
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.control_corner_material);
    int paddingH = res
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_padding_horizontal_material);
    int paddingV = res
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_padding_vertical_material);
    int insetH = context.getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_horizontal_material);
    int insetV = res
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_vertical_material);

    float[] outerRadii = new float[8];
    Arrays.fill(outerRadii, radius);

    RoundRectShape r = new RoundRectShape(outerRadii, null, null);

    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(r);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    shapeDrawable.setPadding(paddingH, paddingV, paddingH, paddingV);

    return new InsetDrawable(shapeDrawable,
            insetH, insetV, insetH, insetV);
}
```

The `color` argument is obtained from theme's `attr/colorButtonNormal` - the same color used with `android:tint` in xml definition.

The `RippleDrawable` created programmatically:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
Drawable createButtonRippleBg(Context context,
                                             int colorButtonNormal,
                                             int colorControlHighlight) {
    return new RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(colorControlHighlight),
                    null, createButtonShape(context, colorButtonNormal));
}
```

I am aware that even though the mask-color/shape is not rendered visually, its alpha *does* affect the `RippleDrawable`. This is not an issue here - all colors being used for the mask have full-blown alpha.

I have also confirmed that the colors being read from attributes - `colorControlHighlight & colorButtonNormal` - are correct for the theme at play.

Yet, the result is:

Xml rendition:

[image]

In Java:

[image]

Interesting bit is that this happens on API 21. On API 22, both approaches produce identical results.

**The question:**

I am certain that this is a bug on API 21. If someone can track this down, we can probably find a multiplier for the alpha/color value to offset this visual difference.

In addition to general good-will, I also promise a bounty as I have already spent quite some time on this.

Comment: The only difference i see is that via xml you set the color as tint `android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal"` and via code you set it as color `shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);`

Comment: @mikepenz Yea, the `color` argument is actually obtained from theme's `colorButtonNormal`. I mentioned this above: _The `color` argument is obtained from theme's `attr/colorButtonNormal` - the same color used with `android:tint` in xml definition_.

Comment: no this is not the thing i mean. You set it as color `shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color)` in the xml as `tint`. why not set it as tint too via code?  `shapeDrawable.setTint();`

Comment: @mikepenz Oh, I see what you mean. I did try that before - the visual difference remained. I also tried applying a `ColorFilter` using `PorterDuffColorFilter` with `Mode.MULTIPLY`. The output was not as expected. Moreover, the problem is not present on API 22 which leads me to believe that the xml rendition on API 21 has a bug.

Comment: oh i see. I can't prove it but as of the screenshots it looks like the xml display on API 21 just draws the shape twice. so it overlaps the same background a second time.

Comment: @mikepenz Could very well be the case. Hope someone can provide an explanation for this.

Comment: This is a good question, I think. Hope someone can provide an explanation here. PS: @mikepenz are you the Mike Penz in my FB friends' list?

Comment: @SilentKnight I don't know. i am this one: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Answer (score 4):

Try this alternate constructor `new RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(colorRipple), backgroundDrawable, null);`

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

$duration: 4s;

.rotate {
    color: aquamarine;    
    position: relative; filter: blur (2px) contrast (4);    
    font-size: 118px;
}
```

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: What is this css supposed to do? Where does it go?